# parsing xml to json through fast-xml-parser changes the string value

Tags: fast-xml-parser

i am parsing a xml having this attribute :  42303933365137544b36  when converting to json the value of sku changes to :  "sku" : "42303933365446540000",

i am using fast-xml-parser in node
Kindy suggest what is the issue and how can we resovle this ..

Comment: the attribute is :  "<SKU>42303933365137544b36</SKU>"

Comment: Assuming you mean the JavaScript library, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Probably you're using the old version of Fast-XML-Parser. This issue had been fixed in recent releases.